# Differences between two bool codes

Tags: c#

This is a quick question about some code I want to use, but I don't have everything clear.

Does this :

```
return <SOMETHING> == <SOMETHING ELSE>;
```

and this :

```
if (<SOMETHING> == <SOMETHING ELSE>)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

mean the same thing ?

Thanks to all who put their time here. Cheers :)

Comment: Do you mean `<SOMETHING> == <SOMETHING_ELSE>` or two values that are known to be equal at compile time?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for that mistake. Question is edited now.

Comment: With the edit, the two are now equivalent. It's up to your preference which to use.

Answer (score 10):

No.

Your first line will return no matter what.
Your second line will only return if the condition is true; if the condition is false, the function will continue executing.

Your first line is equivalent to

```
if (<SOMETHING> == <SOMETHING>)
    return true;
return false;
```

(or with `else`)

---

**EDIT**: Yes; exactly.

Comment: if

else

is what i ment with true (or false).

Thank You :)

Comment: Note: This answer was correct for the original OP; however the OP has been edited in such a way that this answer is no longer correct. (The OP has added an `else` clause.)

Answer (score 1):

First will return the actual result of evaluation

```
return <SOMETHING> == <SOMETHING>;
```

but second can be used to send evaluation or inverse of evaluation.

```
if (<SOMETHING> == <SOMETHING>)
    return true;
```

or

```
if (<SOMETHING> == <SOMETHING>)
    return false;
```

Comment: If you just want to return the inverse of the expression just throw a `!` in front of it, or in this case, just use `!=` instead of `==`.  The only real difference is that the second example only conditionally returns.

Answer (score 1):

```
return <SOMETHING> == <SOMETHING>;
```

alternate of above is

```
if (<SOMETHING> == <SOMETHING>)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```